# Forward Engineering Error 1054 MySQL Workshop

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to forward engineer my database, but this is what popped up.

Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1054: Unknown column '$118.00' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `aml12k`.`book` (`bok_isbn`, `pub_id`, `bok_title`, `bok_pub_date`, `bok_num_pages`, `bok_cost`, `bok_price`, `bok_notes`) VALUES ('1', 1, 'feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam auctor,', '2013-09-01', 46, $118.00, $150.64, 'euismod enim. Etiam gravida molestie arcu.')

SQL script execution finished: statements: 52 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.

Nothing to fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not sanitizing the fields: $118.00 and $150.64 are considered fields, so, you should enclosed them between quotation marks, and try to insert them again:

```
INSERT INTO aml12k.book (bok_isbn, pub_id, bok_title, bok_pub_date, bok_num_pages, bok_cost, bok_price, bok_notes) VALUES ('1', 1, 'feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam auctor,', '2013-09-01', 46, '$118.00', '$150.64', 'euismod enim. Etiam gravida molestie arcu.')
```